# Help installing nokogiri with new libxml2

Tags: ruby

I am getting the following error in nokogiri. I am installing the new library of
libxml2 via fink, when I type "fink list libxml2" I get:

```
i   libxml2          2.7.8-102    XML parsing library, version 2
```

I have also added to my .Profile to the DY_LIBRARY_PATH ... /sw/lib , when I
try to run my program I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.6.16, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
```

How can I install that gem so that it links against the newer libxml2 library? I install the
gem as:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
```

Ted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From nokogiri [wiki](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/wiki/what-to-do-if-libxml2-is-being-a-jerk):

> Specify the libxml2 and libxslt dirs
>   for the installer.  If you’re using
>   fink:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/sw/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/sw/lib --with-xslt-dir=/sw
```

Answer (score 1):

You have read "[Nonstandard libxml2 / libxslt installations](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)" right?

Fink is a non-standard install on Mac OS.

Per the Nokogiri Installation docs:

```
If you’ve got libxml2 and/or libxslt installed in a nonstandard place (read as “not /opt/local, /usr/local, /usr or the standard Ruby directories”), you can use command-line parameters to the gem install command to grease the wheels:

gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-dir=/home/joe/builds \
                        --with-xslt-dir=/home/joe/builds

Or, you can specify include and library directories separately:

gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-lib=/home/joe/builds/lib \
                        --with-xml2-include=/home/joe/builds/include/libxml2 \
                        --with-xslt-lib=/home/joe/builds/lib \
                        --with-xslt-include=/home/joe/builds/include

Note that, by default, libxslt header files are installed into the root include directory, but libxml2 header files are installed into a subdirectory thereof named libxml2.
```

Comment: What is the standard install of libxml2 on MacOS?

Comment: It is the version Apple installs.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the troubles is `sudo`. `nokogiri` installs really easily without any custom flags if you run it on a properly configured environment. Details in a similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30603620/145046