# Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2 with Babun gives error 'libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, libxml2

I'm trying to get Ruby on Rails (Ruby 2.0.0p598, Rails 4.2.0) working on Babun. I've been following this tutorial:

http://xjlin0.github.io/tech/2015/04/14/babun-the-new-cygwin-for-ruby-rails-sinatra-and-nodejs/

Where installing Nokogiri is supposed to be as simple as

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

But it always gives me the same error, as indicated in the title.

I know I already have this installed. I installed `libxml2-dev` as well with Babun's package manager using

```
pact install libxml2-devel
```

I've tried manually downloading another libxml2 package and pointing it that way like

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-config=C:/Ruby/
```

(I put the folder in C:\Ruby). Still, nothing works, and it thinks there's no libxml2 when I definitely have it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 64 bit ruby NokoGiri on windows has problems with that. Try 
 gem install nokogiri --prerelease

More can be read about this here [libxml2 missing for nokogiri gem on Windows 8 x64 with Ruby 1.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014854/libxml2-missing-for-nokogiri-gem-on-windows-8-x64-with-ruby-1-9-3)