# Ruby update error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run following command in Terminal :

```
gem install bundler && bundle install --without test development
```

But get me error about Ruby version, you can see Log in below :

```
successfully installed bundler-1.3.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.3.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.3.5...
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using ffi (1.9.1) 
Using mime-types (1.25) 
Using ethon (0.6.1) 
Using json (1.8.1) 
Using mini_portile (0.5.2) 
Installing nokogiri (1.6.0)

Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

And my Ruby version is : (`ruby -v`)

```
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-02) [i486-linux]
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204152/nokogiri-error-when-running-bundle-install

Comment: I've tried it before but the problem still remain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try gem install nokogiri as you have RVM installed. See here Installing Nokogiri for other things to install with it.

Like below :

## nokogiri requirements

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: First line: `Already installed newest version`. And the second line: `Error installing nokogiri: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.`

Comment: Hope this will help you http://www.andrewsturges.com/2011/09/installing-nokogiri-with-rvm-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: Turned out I was using the default system Ruby (and thus installing all the gems there in /Library/Ruby/Gems) even though rbenv points to ruby-1.9.3 so that's why Nokogiri was complaining.

Fixed this by adding this to $PATH, so rbenv loads before the system ruby:

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Use ruby ruby 1.9.2p320 instead of ruby 1.9.2dev

Answer (score 0):

try this : `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev`