# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) while installing nokogiri -v '1.5.6' Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I got a tough problem in ruby and rails.

I have already installed nokogiri-1.6.0, but the rails says that

```
You have requested:
  nokogiri ~> 1.6.0

The bundle currently has nokogiri locked at 1.5.6.
Try running `bundle update nokogiri`
```

Then I tried "bundle install", it showed the follow:

```
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/johnhenry/valcuqw/vendor/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/johnhenry/valcuqw/vendor/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

In the GEMFILE, I changed to `gem "nokogiri", "~> 1.5.6”`, but it told me that

```
bundle install
Gemfile syntax error:
gem "zip-zip", "~> 0.1" # In Gem hell...
```

I am totally frustrated. Can someone give me a hand? Thanks!

Comment: do you try delete `Gemfile.lock` and `bundle` again?

Comment: can you tell me which command be used to delete Gemfile.lock?

Comment: simple delete file `Gemfile.lock` in Rails root path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the file: Gemfile.lock and had a continious loop of dots,so i restored it after quiting the process with ctrl + c ,so i went into the gemfile.lock file and manually picked the version of nokogiri i wanted,in my case 1.6.2.1, but i used nokogiri (~> 1.6.2),
hope this works for someone

Comment: This looks more like a comment than answer!

Comment: i had deleted the essential part by mistake @PareshMayani

Answer (score 0):

Could possibly be because of the weird `"` symbol you have in the gemfile. See the last character in the nokogiri line?

Comment: Yeah, that is a problem. But after I corrected it and install nokogiri 1.5.6, it showed johnhenytekimbp:valcuqw johnhenry$ gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.6'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/johnhenry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/.autotest
johnhenytekimbp:valcuqw johnhenry$

Comment: `sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.6'`

Comment: But it showed ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/johnhenry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.

Comment: now try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277456/nokogiri-installation-fails-libxml2-is-missing)

Comment: Thanks. but when I run bundle exec rails c, it still showed me an error like this:`require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)