# Can't install Rails on Yosemite - I feel like I've tried everything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I feel like I've read every tutorial and all StackExchange posts, and I still get the same error when trying to install Rails. Here is the common error that I get:

```
$ gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150409-59802-iosiis.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Activating libxml2 2.9.2 (from /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/libxml2/2.9.2)...
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxslt-1.1.28
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch
    - 0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch
    - 0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch
    - 0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch
    - 0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch
    - 0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch
    - 0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch
    - 0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch
    - 0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch
    - 0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch
    - 0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch
    - 0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install
************************************************************************
Extracting libxslt-1.1.28.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.28 (from /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/libxslt/1.1.28)...
checking for main() in -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
    --with-libxml2lib
    --without-libxml2lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

My OS is `OS X Yosemite 10.10.2`

Here's what I have installed so far, I used `RMV` to install Ruby:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]

$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --    with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix

$ gem -v
2.4.6
```

I've used the following to install Rails and keep getting the error above:

```
$ gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc

$ gem install rails -v 4.2.0

$ gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/opt/local/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/opt/local/lib --with-xslt-dir=/opt/local

$ sudo gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

I don't know what else to do, please help.

**@rainkinz:**

```
$ cat /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out

/Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150409-82655-12gg3g1.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Activating libxml2 2.9.2 (from /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/libxml2/2.9.2)...
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxslt-1.1.28
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch
    - 0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch
    - 0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch
    - 0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch
    - 0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch
    - 0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch
    - 0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch
    - 0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch
    - 0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch
    - 0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch
    - 0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch
    - 0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install
************************************************************************
Extracting libxslt-1.1.28.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running patch with /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.28 (from /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/libxslt/1.1.28)...
checking for main() in -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
    --with-libxml2lib
    --without-libxml2lib

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

**Output from `brew doctor`:

```
$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/mann

Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

  /opt/local/bin/libpng-config
  /opt/local/bin/libpng16-config
  /opt/local/bin/ncurses5-config
  /opt/local/bin/ncursesw5-config
  /opt/local/bin/pkg-config
  /opt/local/bin/python2.7-config
  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda/bin/curl-config
  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda/bin/freetype-config
  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda/bin/libdynd-config
  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda/bin/libpng-config
  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda/bin/libpng15-config
  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda/bin/llvm-config
  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda/bin/python-config
  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda/bin/python2-config
  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda/bin/python2.7-config
  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda/bin/xml2-config
  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda/bin/xslt-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4m-config

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
  /opt/local/bin/port

This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may want to
temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.

  sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libMonoPosixHelper.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFFileMonitor.32.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFIPC.32.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFIPC.I.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFsqlite3.7.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSFSyncEngine.I.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
    /usr/local/include/fakepq.h
    /usr/local/include/fakesql.h
    /usr/local/include/itcl.h
    /usr/local/include/itcl2TclOO.h
    /usr/local/include/itclDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/itclInt.h
    /usr/local/include/itclIntDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/itclMigrate2TclCore.h
    /usr/local/include/itclTclIntStubsFcn.h
    /usr/local/include/mysqlStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/odbcStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/pqStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/tcl.h
    /usr/local/include/tclDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclOO.h
    /usr/local/include/tclOODecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclPlatDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclThread.h
    /usr/local/include/tclTomMath.h
    /usr/local/include/tclTomMathDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbc.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbcDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbcInt.h
    /usr/local/include/tk.h
    /usr/local/include/tkDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tkPlatDecls.h

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
    /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a

Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
  /opt/local/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
this other pkg-config.

Warning: Your Xcode (6.2) is outdated
Please update to Xcode 6.3.
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

Comment: are you using homebrew?

Comment: Do you have XCode and the XCode Developer Tools installed?

Comment: yes i am using homebrew

Comment: yes, i have both XCode and XCode dev tools installed

Comment: Can you paste the output of cat /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out?

Comment: here is the output: `cat: /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-s‌​tatic/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you try that again it looks like some odd chars were in the previous comment: `cat /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out`

Comment: there were a couple of spaces in it when I pasted it...see the output above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nokogiri installation fails -libxml2 is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277456/nokogiri-installation-fails-libxml2-is-missing)

Comment: Can you try to find mkmf.log and paste the output of that? It looks like it's building libxml2 fine, but not finding the (newly installed by nokogiri) headers...

Comment: Also, what is the output of `brew doctor`

Comment: /Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.0.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/mkmf.log
/Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/mkmf.log
/Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.0.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/mkmf.log
/Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/mkmf.log
/Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/mkmf.lo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your brew doctor output:

```
sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports
mv  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda  /Users/jdesilvio/anaconda.back

gem install nokogiri
```

then optionally put back macports (you probably shouldn't have both macports and homebrew) and optionally put back anaconda (whatever that is). My guess is that the libxml2 install in that anaconda directory is messing up the path to the headers of the  libxml2 installed by nokogiri.

Comment: `$ brew install libiconv`
`Warning: libiconv-1.14 already installed` and `gem install nokogiri` resulted in the same error

Comment: Son of a Gun...it was the macports! moved that and nokogiri and rails installed! Thanks so much...any idea why macports would cause that? BTW: anaconda is a Python distribution

Comment: Most likely the reason is that when the native nokogiri C code is being compiled it's looking for libxml2 under macports, not finding it and failing. What is the output of echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and $PATH?

Comment: `$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` didnt return anything. `$ echo $PATH
/Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/jdesilvio/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/jdesilvio/.rvm/bin
`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use Ruby Version Manager to do it. It is a bad idea to mess with the ruby version that ships with OSX as Apple relies on certain version to do its up dates.

**Install RVM, Ruby, and Rails**

Disable excess documentation

```
echo "gem: --no-document" >> ~/.gemrc
```

Install RVM w/Ruby and Rails

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles --autolibs=enabled --rails
```

Load RVM in current terminal session

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

If it is not already there, place this in your ~/.profile file to load at every login

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Check if RVM loaded as a function

```
type rvm | head -1
```

Check versions

```
rvm -v
ruby -v
rails -v
```

Comment: I think I have been using RVM to install...when I ran `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles --autolibs=enabled --rails` i got the same error

Comment: not sure where the ~/.profile file is but the `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` should be added after rails is installed??

Comment: Yes, add it after install. Depending on your shell setup it could be ~/.profile, .bashrc, or .zsh that your $PATH variables are read from

Comment: the `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles --autolibs=enabled --rails` install didnt work...should I still update .profile?

Comment: Not unless you have the programs installed in that directory. ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm