# Installing nokogiri failed in OS X 10.10.5

Tags: ruby, xcode, nokogiri, jekyll

I'm following Github's Jekyll installation instructions
https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/

Simply issuing `build install` initially failed to compile libxml2-2.9.2. The log shows it is related to my system library /usr/local/lib/libiconv.dylib not being 64bits : "missing required architecture x86_64 in file /usr/local/lib/libiconv.dylib".

Providing the libraries, like in

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2' -- \
--with-xml2-include=/Applications/Dev/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/ \
--with-iconv-include=/Applications/Dev/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/ \
--with-iconv-lib=/Applications/Dev/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib --use-system-libraries
```

under Xcode, resolves the 64bit issue with iconv but **systematically fails at the point of finding libxml2**. See the log below.

I've tried all options I could use from [Error to install Nokogiri on OSX 10.9 Maverick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643153/error-to-install-nokogiri-on-osx-10-9-maverick?lq=1)
and
[Nokogiri installation fails -libxml2 is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277456/nokogiri-installation-fails-libxml2-is-missing)
but with no avail. I also installed fink and libmxl2 and pointed to the include files and libraries there but it failed as well at the same point.

I have a fresh update of Xcode 6.4, and made sure to issue a *xcode-select --install*. Homebrew is not an option for me.

Below the log of my last try with the Xcode libraries& include paths.

Where is that mkmf.log file mentioned in the log?? Judging from the other threads I was hoping to solve the problem and it seems I'd be close to it, but after a day dealing with all this I can't see now how.

Thanks in advance for any hint on how to solve this.

PS: I just wanted to try out blogging in github. Isn't all this ruby mambo-jambo supposed to be easier than the good old cmake, dpkg, etc.? I can't quite get the right mindset to this trend of plethora of package & version managers each with their own idiosyncrasy. Does this approach of rbenv, gem, bunlder, etc. get more reliable after one gets used to it? or is it always this fragile? Just wondering whether is worth the effort to get familiar with all this..

PS2: **Installation log** as given by 
~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out

```
/Users/masl/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150822-64326-2krxl7.rb extconf.rb --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Dev/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/ --with-iconv-include=/Applications/Dev/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/ --with-iconv-lib=/Applications/Dev/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib --use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
libxml2 version 2.9.2 or later is highly recommended, but proceeding anyway.
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/masl/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-exslt-dir
    --without-exslt-dir
    --with-exslt-include
    --without-exslt-include=${exslt-dir}/include
    --with-exslt-lib
    --without-exslt-lib=${exslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libexslt-config
    --without-libexslt-config
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
    --with-libxml2lib
    --without-libxml2lib

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Comment: Maybe you need to specify `--with-xml2-lib=/Applications/Dev/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib`?

Comment: Also, note the line: `libxml2 version 2.9.2 or later is highly recommended, but proceeding anyway.`. I think xcode comes with version 2.2.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks, that worked! Btw, why this down voting?

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2' -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/lib
```