# Impossible to install Nokogiri in Rails app Since OSX Mojave 10.14.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, macos-mojave

Since the recent update (10.14.2) Nokogiri gem cannot be installed in my app.

When I run `bundle install`, I get this error:

```
./siteconf20190109-70456-1diyett.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE
-fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future...
no
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
Using pkg-config gem version 1.3.2
checking for libxml-2.0... yes
checking for libxslt... yes
checking for libexslt... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I already checked the  [Nokogiri's installation guide](https://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#unable-to-find-libraries-on-macos-mojave) for Mojave, but it does not work, even after having used this patch:

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

**Setup:**

**OS:** 
OSX Mojave 10.14.2

**Ruby version:** 
ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-darwin17]

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Did it not work for you => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277456/nokogiri-installation-fails-libxml2-is-missing ?

Comment: Try to reduce the version number in the Gemfile until it works. Use `gem list --all --exact nokogiri` to see all possible versions. (I'm guessing at the options.) Then use `gem 'nokogiri', '~>1.2.3.4'` to get up to 1.2.3.9 or just set it exactly.

Comment: @Chloe, the only output  I got when I enter the command  `gem list --all --exact nokogiri` is `*** LOCAL GEMS ***

nokogiri (1.8.4)`

Answer (score 1):

The log message is saying libxml2 is missing.
So, try to run this:

```
   brew install libxml2
```

if you have homebrew installed.
Check this [link](http://macappstore.org/libxml2/) for more information.